# gnome-terminal with Solarized theme has bad colors at ssh-connected machine

Tags: ssh, colors, color-scheme, gnome-terminal

I'm using solarized theme in Gnome-terminal at my Fedora workstation and everything works fine.
[image]

If I connect to different (Ubuntu) host via ssh, I get grayed colors e.g. if I use ls --colors.

[image]

How can I change color settings at remote machine so it has same colors as my local machine? dircolors gave me same results on both workstations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $LS_COLORS variable on remote-host.

Comment: That's it, thanks! I thought _dircolors_ output generates same LS_COLOR, but obviously something was different.